# Wordpress comment_form() does not display actual comments

Tags: functions, comments

Maybe I did not understand the role of comment_form().

**After pasting this in my wordpress single.php I get just the form for submitting comments but NOT THE ACTUAL COMMENTS.**

Is this a bug, or the comment_form() does not handle listing the comments?

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to list comments use [wp_list_comments()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments)

functions' names tell for themselves, your CO